# Finding a phone number by entering a string SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find the phone number in the database by entry into the string, while I wrote this. But if, for example, the number starts with +3 and not only with +7. Any help would be welcome. in SQL I am newbie

For example, there is a Users table with a phone column. There are numbers starting at + 7, + 3. How can I display both options in one query?

SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+7%'

SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+3%'

how to combine this into one query? or does this answer the question "Finding a phone number by entering a string"

Comment: Please provide sample data and the output you want to obtain from that data, as well as your schema, and a tag for the specific DBMS you're using. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576). *by entry into the string* is very unclear, as is what you're actually trying to do. You need to [edit] your question and be much more specific.

Comment: A partial answer is `SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+7%' OR phone LIKE '+3%'`

Comment: Is the `+` really stored in the d/b phone data?  I would expect that would *not* be stored and code surrounding query generation would handle it appropriately.

Comment: To answer your question you should clearly formulate the requirement and then transform it into the algorithm. I cannot imagine you can have not a phone number in phone number column, so do not understand why you try to extract it from that column with some tricks.

Comment: Also, your query retrieves all the data from `workers` table, not a phone number. What is the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two approaches to consider:

```
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+7%' OR phone LIKE '+3%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+7%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE phone LIKE '+3%'
```